# Error installing SoapUI eclipse plugin from update site

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, soapui

I want to install eclipse soapUI plugin, but link is not working when I click on "install new software" and add that URL then it is showing

> Could not find http://www.soapui.org/eclipse/update/site.xml

I am doing installation as given in this site http://www.soapui.org/soapui-for-ide/eclipse/eclipse-plugin.html.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't get my hopes up for it to work. IntelliJ, NetBeans and Eclipse plugins haven't been maintained for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, as per the link you provided, did you read the part:

> An eclipse update site is now available at **http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui-eclipse-plugin**.

As was already mentioned, the last Eclipse plugin was released for SoapUI version 4.0.1 in 2011. After that it was abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this plugin has been discontinued by [SmartBear](http://smartbear.com) and doesn't work on latest versions of Eclipse, anyway if you have an old version of Eclipse ([Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/indigo/)), you can still install the plugin downloading the latest archive release from [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui-eclipse-plugin/4.0.1/) and proceeding with an installation from the local archive :

[image: Eclipse Plugin Installation]

The only worth mentioning alternative available at the moment, that works correctly with latest Eclipse Mars is : [HTTP4e](http://www.nextinterfaces.com) .

Comment: HTTP4e can't send SOAP envelope.